# Bivariate tables on R

Tags: r, csv

I have been trying to create bivariate tables on R using the summary(univariateTable function.
I have been trying

```
write.csv(
  summary(univariateTable(subgroup1+subgroup2~
                            variable    + variable
```

Which should mean stratification along the two subgroups of all variables..
But I keep getting an error: non numeric argument to binary operator. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Please share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with an example input.

Comment: Are you trying to add two factors?